# Rails BigDecimal JSON output for Highcharts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, highcharts, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to make an api endpoint to output BigDecimal numbers as "numbers" in JSON. [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) requires any numeral value to be a number instead of a string. But I couldn't make a JSON object with the BigDecimal numbers shown as real numbers, not strings or anything else.

I need to generate something like this:

```
[[123000, 235436.352642],[127000, 9434.2352663], ... ]
```

There are many answers to this question on the web like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25409406/ruby-on-rails-how-to-generate-an-array-from-records-to-display-in-highcharts), but all of them suggest to convert the BigDecimal to Float via `.to_f`. And that, doesn't make any sense, cause we use decimals to have an exact precision which is not the case with Float.

Comment: `HighCharts` is a frontend library, that is, well, javascript. One might preserve whatever, but javascript will use floats anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You could "round" those numbers, to "numbers"

```
v = BigDecimal("7.176231231231231")
sprintf("%.6f", v)
# => "7.176231"
```

And you could also string `truncate` onto the function to get more specific, rounded numbers(might be useful when using this data for graphs).

```
v = BigDecimal("7.176231231231231")    
sprintf("%.6f", v)
# => "7.176231"
sprintf("%.6f", v.truncate(2))
# => "7.170000"
```